# Second word is out of the circle

Tags: css

Initially, I want to put words into this circle. Maximum character number is 20.

I want to set font size around 24px and the circle's width and height are 100px;

However, the 2nd word fell outside of the circle.

Can anyone help?
http://codepen.io/yumikohey/pen/ocFtJ

Here is my code.

```
<div class="blog_circle">
   Channel Buzz  
</div>

.blog_circle{
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:24px;
    color:#000;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#45C2B3;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

On the other hand, how to make the font size change depends on user's inputs?

Answer (score 2):

why do you have a `line-height:100px`? It is too high and that is what is causing it to fall outside the circle......

change it to say `40px`........here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z7aec6w5/1/)

## UPDATE:

add `display:table-cell;` to your style. This will center the text vertically in your div. when you actually inspect element and look at the div, the text is at the center of the div vertically. Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z7aec6w5/3/)

Comment: if i change line-height to 40px, the first word will go up. I want the words to be very center. And the words are close to each other.

Comment: @YumikoHuang: glad the solution works for you.Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

your circle is actually a square with width and height of 100px and its corners are trimmed by a distance of 50px giving the visual of a circle.

now you have your words with their font sizes but you also have line-height mentioned as 100px . Now this is like , imagine a page of ruled paper ( the one that has lines to write) line height defines the size between two lines. now in your case the line height is 100px which is the height of your entire box. If you lower the line height to say 50px (which will give you 2 lines to write on inside that 100px height box) it should work.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try using `padding` and changing `line-height` and a few other things.  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sErgL)